# How can I export my wallet from blockchain.info to Multibit?

Tags: blockchain.info, multibit, import, private-key-export

I need to export my wallet from blockchain.info to Multibit, but i have no idea how to do it, can you please help me? thank you

Comment: Hi David, welcome to Bitcoin.SE. We already have a question that matches yours closely. There is an answer there that might help you, so I've closed your question as a duplicate. However, I've noticed that the answer on it is somewhat old, so I've edited the other question and posted  a bounty on, requesting an updated answer. I hope that the answer helps you, but hopefully an updated answer will get posted there soon.